# How to create an array of custom java object class in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

This is my code. I would like to make an array of **Fruit** (an custom java object class).

```
(defn build-fruit
  [part]
  (let [name (:name part)
        color (:color part)
        price (:price part)
        is_available (:is_available part)]
  (-> (Fruit/newBuilder)
      (.setName name)
      (.setColor color)
      (.setPrice price)
      (.setIsAvailable is_available)
      (.build))))

(defn build-fruits
  [result length]
  (loop [remaining-fruits result
         final-fruits (make-array Fruit length)]
    (if (empty? remaining-fruits)
      final-fruits
      (let [[part & remaining] remaining-fruits]
        (recur remaining
               (into-array final-fruits (build-fruit part)))))) ;got an error here
  )

(defn -getAllFruits [this ^Empty req ^StreamObserver res]
  (let [result (clj-grpc.database/findAllFruit)
        length (count result)
        fruits (build-fruits result length)]
    (doto res
      (.onNext (-> (ListOfFruits/newBuilder)
                   (.addAllFruit fruits)
                   (.build)))
      (.onCompleted))))
```

But got an error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Lorg.example.fruitproto.Fruit; cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
    at clojure.core$into_array.invokeStatic(core.clj:3431)
    at clojure.core$into_array.invoke(core.clj:3431)
    at clj_grpc.fruitservice$build_fruits.invokeStatic(fruitservice.clj:118)
    at clj_grpc.fruitservice$build_fruits.invoke(fruitservice.clj:110)
```

My guess is I cann't use `make-array`. I also can't use simple array like this `[]` because it also got another error. What is the proper way to achieve this?

Comment: It is often more helpful to provide a repro that is not dependent on any Java libraries, so people can more easily help you.

Comment: `into-array` has a 2-arity version, where the first argument is a component type. Note the second argument is a sequence, so there's no need for using a loop in `build-fruits`. I would provide a code sample, but as Michiel points out, the repro code in the question is not standalone, so it's hard to provide an example.

Comment: See https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/into-array

Comment: @SteffanWestcott without loop? How do i build Fruit object for every item in result variable?

Comment: See my answer below, building an array of `LocalDate`, where `map` is used to transform the input maps to `LocalDate` instances.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a standalone example of using `into-array`, building an array of `LocalDate` rather than `Fruit`:

```clj
(ns overflow.example
  (:import (java.time LocalDate)))

(defn build-local-date [{:keys [year month day]}]
  (LocalDate/of year month day))

(defn build-local-dates [xs]
  (into-array LocalDate (map build-local-date xs)))
```